# Why is .NET MAUI app not running after compile?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, maui

this might sound like a novice or stupid question (it probably is).

But I created a very simple .NET MAUI app, almost the same as the default template with slight modifications. It runs well in the editor (default debug, any cpu config), but it won't run the .exe after build.

Build is correct and .EXE is generated, but when trying to run it (regardless of admin rights) it doesn't open any window. Checked the task manager and it opens a task with the exe name that terminates instantly.

Any ideas on why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been asked a couple of times before with answers as well: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaui%5D+exe+run

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I have already seen all of these posts. They are building the app via commands or using other forms of getting an executable from the .NET MAUI project. I want to use  the Visual Studio built-in "Build".

Maybe this is some preview error or happening only in my machine.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use command-line or not. Running the exe like that is called "unpackaged publish" which is not supported right now.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and I solved by **installing WinUI3** from Windows Store:
https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/winui-3-gallery/9P3JFPWWDZRC?hl=en-us&gl=us

To explain: .NET MAUI can run on Windows 10, but only by installing the WinUI3 mentioned above.
These are the requirements:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: I couldn't believe that would work, tried it anyway, and yes I can confirm that strangely works.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Microsoft should consider adding this step to their tutorial: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/maui/first-app-tutorial/run

Answer (score 3):

It's because MSIX Packaging. It's solved by Microsoft already. Please check [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3166) issue from MAUI's official GitHub repo.

Add this lines to your `csproj` file;

```
<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained Condition="'$(IsUnpackaged)' == 'true'">true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
<SelfContained Condition="'$(IsUnpackaged)' == 'true'">true</SelfContained>
```

change your `launchSettings.json` file like this;

```
{
    "profiles": {
        "Windows Machine": {
        "commandName": "Project"
        ,
    }
}
```

and you have to [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads) the Windows App SDK runtime and MSIX packages if it's not installed already.

Comment: This works as expected